QGIS export Atlas with dynamic legend
I am trying to print an Atlas layout so that the legend is dynamically updated depending on what is visible on each Atlas page. However, when I go to do this, only the legend on the first page is shown and copied on the proceeding exported pages. Is there something I am doing wrong? The only workaround I have found is to cycle through each page manually, export them as a PDF, and then merge them outside of QGIS, which takes a lot of time.
For context, I have "auto-update legend" off and "only show items inside current atlas feature" on. I am trying to do this by using the "export Atlas as PDF" feature" with single file export on. I am using QGIS 3.34.11-Prizren

I venture a strongly informed guess you need to enable "auto-update legend" - but I didn't verify it. Is there a reason you turned off that feature?

Auto-update legend often shows raster layers and other items you might not necessarily want in a legend. I have encountered this bug before albeit in older versions. Have you tried maybe switching off 'only show items inside current atlas feature' and instead using 'only show items inside map extent' to see if it works (not exactly the same thing though, I know).

@she_weeds I have tried both ways with only having 'only show items inside current atlas feature' on and separately only having 'only show items inside map extent'. Both still resulted in the legend showing only what was visible on the first atlas map.
